# Why charge density is higher in the sharp edges of conductor?

Tags: electrostatics

If we have a conductor which is in electrostatic equilibrium, then the charge distribution over this surface $\sigma$ is greatest at the sharp edges of that surface.
Why is this the case?
It is somehow acceptable Intuitivly but I couldn't prove this statement mathematically.
None of the questions before gave a non intuitive answer.

[image: Conductor]

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64639/

Comment: Also: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/103048/charge-distribution-on-conductors http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/188226/why-charge-distribution-is-greatest-at-pointy-edges-of-a-surface?rq=1

Comment: It is obvious Intuitivly but Wanted to find a mathematical proof.

Comment: @bemoniri : The 2nd ans of the duplicate question does give the mathematical proof.